# Can't start headless chrome

Tags: php, laravel, selenium-chromedriver, laravel-dusk

I tried to use Laravel Dusk programmatically. When I try the below code:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;

$driver = realpath(base_path() . '/vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux');

$process = new Process(
    array_merge([realpath($driver)], []), null, ['DISPLAY' => ':0']
);

$process->start();

$options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([]);
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
    ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
);

return RemoteWebDriver::create(
    'http://localhost:9515', $capabilities, 5000, 10000
);
```

I'm getting this error. I tried to use FacebookWebDriver as standalone component and also get the same result:

```
Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: 
{"desiredCapabilities": 
{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","chromeOptions": 
{"binary":""}}} Operation timed out after 10001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

The port is in question is not in use. Couldn't find out what is wrong with the code.

Comment: Same error with direct localhost ip

Comment: What's the result of `vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux --v`? What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I already solved this issue by putting Selenium Standalone jar and chromedriver-linux executable in the same directory

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved this by putting Selenium Standalone jar and chromedriver in the same directory. Be sure to include the folder directory in your path. Might come handy to somebody else.